# How to do RegularExpressionValidations in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a text box to check if it does not accept certain special characters. Nearly some 10 special charaters it should not accept. On entering wrong special characters the RegularExpressionValidator throws red asterisk * symbol mark. I don't know how to capture the red symbol mark when wrong charaters are given. Please find below the sample code.

```
 String[] invalidChars = {"%", "/", "\\", "&", "?", ";", ":", "!"};
    for (String invalid : invalidChars) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtbox")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtbox")).sendKeys(invalid);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnSubmit")).click();
    .......................
```

dont know how to capture the RegularExpressionValidator asterisk * symbol that appears when wrong charaters are given.

Html code

```
<input name="txtbox" type="text" maxlength="150" id="id" tabindex="3"    class="Inputfield" style="width:100%;resize:none" />
<span controltovalidate="txtbox" id="ControlValidator" evaluationfunction="RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid" validationexpression="[^\%\/\\\&amp;\?\,\'\;\:\!\-]*" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;"> * </span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: need to see the related html in order to show you how to select it

Comment: i have added the Html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it easily by xpath (**and** operator) ie) checking if the id of the element is validator and also if the text is displayed

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='ControlValidator' and contains(text(), '*')]");
```

EDIT:

```
 // Chk if element is present or not

    boolean b=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='yourid' and contains(text(), '*')]").isDisplayed();

    System.out.println(b);

    //If it returns true then the respective element * appears on the screen

    //There is no need to get the css value visibility
```

Hope this helps you...kindly get back if you have any queries

Comment: why do you want to get the css value. isDisplayed method will return true or false based on the element visibilty on screen .pls refer my edit

Comment: Happy to be of help..:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of css property visibility.

Selects the validator:

```
WebElement validator = driver.findElement(By.Id("validator"));
```

finds out if its hidden or visible:

```
String asterisk = validator.getCssValue("visibility");
```

So if `asterisk.equals('hidden')` then the input is legit, if its `asterisk.equals('visible')` then you have illiegal characters.

Comment: shouldnt be, can you share the url?

Comment: Are you getting the css value before you enter any text? or after you enter text? if you open up firebug and enter some invalid characters into the textbox, as soon as the red asterisk appears the visibility property shoud change to visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working fine. I gave the ID wrongly. sorry.